# How to get hex values from string?

Tags: c, hex

I have a function with an input parameter "text" , which consists of a string containing unknown number of 2-character Hexadecimal numbers separated by space. I need to read them and put them in separate array indexes or read them in for loop and work with them one by one. Each of these values represents an encrypted char(the hex values are ascii values of the characters). How could i do that? I think i should use sscanf(); but i can't figure out how to do it.

```
char* bit_decrypt(const char* text){
    int size=strlen(text)/3;
    unsigned int hex[size];
    char*ptr;
    for(int i=0; i<size+1; i++){
        hex[i] = strtoul(text, &ptr, 16);
        printf("%x ",hex[i]);
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

---

```
output is: "80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80 80"
should be: "80 9c 95 95 96 11 bc 96 b9 95 9d 10"
```

Comment: What code do you have?

Comment: `sscanf` wouldn't help you since you don't know where the numbers are. I would say you are on your own: traverse the string in the search of `0-9A-H`'s. Or use regular expressions.

Comment: i know the string is in format: "80 9c 95 95 96 11 bc 96 b9 95 9d 10"

Comment: You might be able to use `strtoul()`, with a `base` argument of 16, in a loop.  It'll convert one hexadecimal number, stopping at a space, *and* it'll return you a pointer to the end of the number it converted, which is precisely the pointer you need to call `strtoul` on during the next trip around your loop..

Comment: could you please help me with it? im a student and ive never used it before. maybe if you could show me some example using similiar string as i mentioned above

Comment: i think i figured it out! thank you! strtoul() is very useful!

Comment: @wannacode1881 Good job! I knew you could. :-)

Comment: please take a look at the edit. im kind of stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You scan always the first value of `text`, because you forgot to move the input for `strtoul` right after the end of the previous scan. That's what the `**end`-parameter of `strtoul` is good for: it points to the character right after the last digit of a successful scan. Note: if nothing could have been read in, the `end`-pointer is equal the input pointer, and this indicates a "wrongly formated number" or the end of the string. See the following program illustrating this. Hope it helps.

```
int main() {

    const char* input = "80 9c 95 95 96 11 bc 96 b9 95 9d 10";
    const char *current = input;
    char *end = NULL;
    while (1) {
        unsigned long val = strtoul(current, &end, 16);
        if (current == end) // invalid input or end of string reached
            break;

        printf("val: %lX\n", val);

        current = end;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also possible solution with the use of `strchr`,  and `strtoul(tmp,NULL,16);`

In your solution remember that `size_t arr_len = (len/3) + 1;` since the last token is only `2` bytes long.

Input `text` tokens are converted to bytes and stored in `char array`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
  char text[] = "80 9c 95 95 96 11 bc 96 b9 95 9d 10";

  size_t len = strlen(text);
  size_t arr_len = (len/3) + 1;

  printf("len= %zu arr_len= %zu\n", len, arr_len);
  printf("Text:\n%s\n", text);

  char array[arr_len];
  const char *p1 = text;

  char tmp[3];
  tmp[2] = 0;

  printf("Parsing:\n");     
  for(size_t i=0; i< arr_len; i++)
  {
       p1 = strchr(p1,' ');

       if(p1)
       {
           tmp[0] = *(p1-2);
           tmp[1] = *(p1-1);

           array[i]= (char)strtoul(tmp,NULL,16);
           printf("%2x ", (unsigned char) array[i]);

           p1++;

           if(strlen(p1) == 2 ) // the last char
           {
               i++;

               tmp[0] = *(p1);
               tmp[1] = *(p1+1);

               array[i]= (char)strtoul(tmp,NULL,16);
               printf("%2x", (unsigned char) array[i]);
           }
       }
  }

  printf("\nArray content:\n"); 
  for(size_t i=0; i< arr_len; i++)
  {
    printf("%2x ", (unsigned char) array[i]);  
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Test:

```
len= 35 arr_len= 12
Text:
80 9c 95 95 96 11 bc 96 b9 95 9d 10
Parsing:
80 9c 95 95 96 11 bc 96 b9 95 9d 10
Array content:
80 9c 95 95 96 11 bc 96 b9 95 9d 10
```

Comment: it works , but not in mine case, because my parameter is const char. the   char *p1 = text; line makes a problem

Comment: bmp.c:266:14: error: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Werror=discarded-qualifiers]
   char *p1 = text;

Comment: @wannacode1881 Just declare  `const char *p1 = text;` The buffer `text` is not modified.

Comment: yes. i just wanted to point that out. that p1 has to be const also. thank you